# The most sensible approach to components with view/edit modes in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-form

I'm creating a component that displays details about an item chosen from a list - here's a diagram that illustrates the current architecture:

[image]

Here's how it works:

1. `ItemList.js` makes a call to Firebase via a Redux action creator/reducer, returning a list of all items
2. Our user taps an item, and `react-native-router-flux` passes all the chosen item as props to `ItemView.js`
3. `ItemView.js` passes an array of attributes from `this.props` to `ItemDetails.js`, which renders them in a UI card

This approach works OK for displaying attributes, but now I want to reuse `ItemView.js` to allow users to edit attributes and save their changes - what's the best approach here?

I thought I'd create an edit toggle in `this.state`, store any changes to the input fields in `this.state`, and then fire an action creator to update the entry.

My concern is that the attributes are originally in `this.props`, so switching between `props` and `state` for edit mode feels a bit iffy.

I considered using an action creator to update `this.props` with changes, but I can't see how that would work, given the props displayed in `ItemDetails.js` are passed all the way down from `ItemList.js`.